# Paying out to Merchants in Stripe

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, payout

I am new to Stripe and I am making an e-commerce site where customers can buy digital art and resell it. I am able to charge the customer fine, but I do not know how to pay out to customers with Stripe. I have tried to use Stripe Connect, but I keep getting error messages which I cannot fix.
My Code:

```
let account = await this.stripe.accounts.create({
            type: 'custom',
            country: 'US',
            email: user.email,
            capabilities: {
                card_payments: {
                    requested: true,
                },
                transfers: {
                    requested: true,
                },
            },
            business_type: 'individual',
        })

        await this.stripe.customers.create({
            name: user.name,
            email: user.email,
            source
        }, {
            stripeAccount: account.id
        })
```

The error:

```
Your account cannot currently make charges. To find out why charge creation is currently disabled, look at the `requirements.disabled_reason` property on this account (/v1/accounts/acct_****************).
```

Comment: Stripe is built as a one-way system: "customers" who make payments, and "users" (often connected accounts) that your "platform" helps to get paid by customers.  It is NOT AT ALL symmetrical - you charge customers, and you pay users.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the country, Service Agreement, Business type and capabilities, onboarding a Stripe custom Connect account requires you (platform) to gather information from the users for verification purpose.

You can view the requirements on this [page](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/required-verification-information)

Comment: I don't see which other information I need to add.